# how can I put a border around a dataframe with xlsxwriter?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I'm writing a dataframe to Excel and need to put a border around the whole dataframe. I'm finding it quite difficult.

Given a typical case:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='xlsxwriter')    
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'great', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['great']
```

The only way I've found to write a border is like this, but you need to write the data (header in this example) and format with a border.

```
headers = df.columns
row_index = 10
start_col = 0
end_col = start_col + len(headers)

for i in range(start_col, end_col):
    worksheet.write(row_index, i, headers[i-start_col], format2)
```

I don't need to write the data - it's already in the dataframe. I just want to put a line at the bottom at the least, and preferably a box around the whole thing.

How to do it?